# Add letters/numbers to pages on publish/update

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to create some post meta for each page on Wordpress.  The point of this is kind of for categorization.  Each top level page will have a letter, like A B C D, etc.  Each child page of a top level page will have a number like 01,02,03,04.  Im trying to modify my code for the publish/update/delete to add/update the meta accordingly no matter if page is deleted or added.  My question is how do I check if it is a top level page or a child page being saved?  The code seems like it is only using the top level section of the code and a different letter is being saved no matter if parent or not.

```
function updateNumbers($post) {
    global $wpdb;
    $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page' ";
    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
    if($post->post_parent > 0) {
        //Child Page
        $counts = 01;
        if ($pageposts):
        foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
        $counts++;
        $parent_letter = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'incr_letter', true);
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts, true);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts);
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_letter', $parent_letter, true);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_letter', $parent_letter);
        endforeach;
        endif;
    }else {
        //Top Level Page
        $counts = A;
        if ($pageposts):
        foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
        $counts++;
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_letter', $counts, true);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_letter', $counts);
        endforeach;
        endif;
    }
}

add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'deleted_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'edit_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

Desired hierarchy would be similar to this:

```
- Page 1 - A.01
- Page 2 - B.01
 -- Page 2 Child - B.02
 -- Page 2 Child - B.03
 -- Page 2 Child - B.04
- Page 3 - C.01
- Page 4 - D.01
```

Comment: well you are looping over all posts whenever 1 post is saved and changing  all posts based on that value.

Comment: @David, right but for some reason it is not determining and running the appropriate function on whether it is a parent or child page.  All pages just get a sequintial letter, no number, no hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues:

1. Your querystring was wrong
2. $counts in your else statement is missing the ""
3. What your code will actually do is loop over every post based on the value of the current post being saved, so if it is a parent, all looped posts will be parents
4. You should check if `$post->post_parent == 0` rather than not greater than 0 which can be true if 0 is passed as a string.

Anyway:

```
function updateNumbers($post) {
    global $wpdb;

    // you had your query wrong..the loop was prob empty..
    $querystr = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page' ";
    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

    if($post->post_parent == 0) {
        //Top Level Page
        $counts = "A"; //string

        // Loop over all posts for every save, update, etc..... expensive   
    }else {
        // Loop over all posts for every save, update, etc..... expensive   
    }


}
```

But what you are trying to do already exists, wp has its system to identify child of etc.